# Paste clipboard data as plain text Service?

Tags: services, copy-paste

Is there a Mac OS X service that takes clipboard data and pastes it as plain text? Or an easy way to create one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple options, gleefully swiped from [Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040204170653788):

Applescript, converting pasteboard contents to plain text and pasting:

```
tell application "Finder" to set frontApp to (name of 1st process whose frontmost = true)
tell application frontApp
    activate
    set clip to «class ktxt» of ((the clipboard as text) as record)
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using {command down}
end tell
```

Shell script, save it in your Scripts folder and chmod 755

```
#!/bin/sh
pbpaste | pbcopy
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using {command down}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any way to convert the AppleScript to a service in Automator which takes in no input and prints out the text instead of sending Command-V? I'm trying to do this myself, but I'm getting several bugs in the code.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by converting the shell script to an Automator Service. I was never able to get the AppleScript to work in the same way.